# Customization of registration form in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I am new to Prestashop framework(v 1.6) and I need to do changes to the theme.

In prestashop registration form I am getting a page like follows.

[image: anyhow i need to change the attributes of that form like add new field or remove a field that is already existed]

Where can I find the source html code part of this page and how can I delete fields of this page. If I remove the fields from the form will it affect any other functionalities of the page? (As example how can I remove birthday field from this form?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should edit `themes/default-bootsrap/authentication.tpl`. The form starts at this line:

```
<form action="{$link->getPageLink('authentication', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post" id="account-creation_form" class="std box">
```

You can remove the optional fields (e.g., `Date of Birth`) without any consequences.

To remove `Date of Birth` delete these lines:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{l s='Date of Birth'}</label>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <select id="days" name="days" class="form-control">
                <option value="">-</option>
                {foreach from=$days item=day}
                    <option value="{$day}" {if ($sl_day == $day)} selected="selected"{/if}>{$day}&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                {/foreach}
            </select>
            {*
                {l s='January'}
                {l s='February'}
                {l s='March'}
                {l s='April'}
                {l s='May'}
                {l s='June'}
                {l s='July'}
                {l s='August'}
                {l s='September'}
                {l s='October'}
                {l s='November'}
                {l s='December'}
            *}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <select id="months" name="months" class="form-control">
                <option value="">-</option>
                {foreach from=$months key=k item=month}
                    <option value="{$k}" {if ($sl_month == $k)} selected="selected"{/if}>{l s=$month}&nbsp;</option>
                {/foreach}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <select id="years" name="years" class="form-control">
                <option value="">-</option>
                {foreach from=$years item=year}
                    <option value="{$year}" {if ($sl_year == $year)} selected="selected"{/if}>{$year}&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                {/foreach}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Make sure that during development `Template compilation` is set to `Force compilation` and `Cache` is set to `No` in PrestaShop back-office -> `Advanced Parameters` -> `Performance`.

Comment: **Note 1**: The code is present twice at 132-174 and 462-504. It is the second occurrence that must be removed (took me quite sometime to figured it out after deleting only the first occurrence).
**Note 2**: I didn't had to turn off the cache, the "*clear cache*" button in the upper right corner did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

'**Date of Birth**' can be entered in 3 places:

- \themes\your-theme\authenticate.tpl  - Registering new account
- \themes\your-theme\identity.tpl - Viewing account details
- \themes\your-theme\order-opc-new-account.tpl - One Page Checkout

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get rid of the Date of birth in Backoffice.
Go to Localization->Countries, then edit your country. There you have an adressformat field where you can drag or delete what fields that should be shown